# Post to multiple accounts on twitter using API. getting duplicate status error.

Tags: php, api, twitter, twitter-oauth, laravel-5.1

Trying to post to twitter using laravel [and this twitter API package](https://github.com/thujohn/twitter). Im using a foreach loop to grab each of the account tokens and post but I keep getting the error Duplicate status because it seems like its not changing the tokens before its posting to twitter. I've tried to refresh the page and the break the connection, still getting the error.

here is my foreachloop

```
foreach ($post['accountsToPost'] as $accountToPost) {
            $uniqueProfile= DB::table('profiles')->where('social_media_id', $accountsToPost)->first();
            $new_token = [
                'oauth_token'        => $uniqueProfile_test->oauth_token,
                'oauth_token_secret' => $uniqueProfile_test->oauth_secret,
                'x_auth_expires'     => $uniqueProfile_test->x_auth_expires,
            ];

            Session::forget('access_token');
            Session::put('access_token', $new_token);
            Twitter::postTweet(['status' => $post['post_text'], 'format' => 'json']);
            Session::flash('flash_message', 'Success! Your post has been sent.');
        }
```

Into the foreach loop im passing in
1. The social media I.D
2. The Oauth, secret tokens
3. The content to post

When I track the tokens using echo it seems to be getting all the right tokens but just not when posting to twitter. Could it be a connection issue? thats its not refreshing the connection for each account?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Figured it out. For anyone else that has the same problem with the package. Don't use session:: commands in the foreach loop. Use the Twitter::reconfig method. Not sure why but on post the session wasn't changing the tokens while in the foreach loop no matter what I tried. Using the reconfig method solved all the token issues.